# Stop buffering HTML5 video, but preserve buffered data. And then resume

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

I am working in a project where you can switch between two or more videos.

So if **Video-A** is playing and I switch to **Video-B** I want to be able to stop buffering **Video-A**, start buffering and play **Video-B**. Then if you want to go back to **Video-B**, stop **B** and resume **A**, without having to start buffering again.

I want to prevent the App of having to buffer more than one Video at a time to save bandwith.

So far the only soluton I found is to remove the source of the video and the putting it again.

```
video.src = ""
```

I don't like this solution.  I would love to have this available within the Video API, like:

```
video.stopBuffering()
vide.resumeBuffering()
```

But it doesn't seems to be the case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer: It can not be done.

There is no API exposing methods to do this, and it's almost entirely up to the browser how to handle the actual loading/buffering strategy (there are some defined steps, but the strategy is not).

### A little on the internals defined in the **[standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#loading-the-media-resource)**:

> The rate of the download may [also] be throttled automatically by the
> user agent, e.g. to balance the download with other connections
> sharing the same bandwidth.
>
> User agents may decide to not download more content at any time, e.g.
> after buffering five minutes of a one hour media resource, while
> waiting for the user to decide whether to play the resource or not,
> while waiting for user input in an interactive resource [...]

and

> The user agent may use whatever means necessary to fetch the resource
> (within the constraints put forward by this and other specifications);
> for example, reconnecting to the server in the face of network errors,
> using HTTP range retrieval requests, or switching to a streaming
> protocol. The user agent must consider a resource erroneous only if it
> has given up trying to fetch it.

You can always pause the video. This could make the browser suspend downloading the data after some seconds, but again, it is up to the browser how to actually deal with this.

So, in conclusion: Whether we like this or not, it's just the way it is.

Comment: I wish you were right, but the browser continue buffering both videos even when one or both are paused!

Comment: @limoragni yes, I state "It's entirely up to the browser to handle the loading/buffering strategy.". Using pause() is your only option of influence (if any)

Answer (score 1):

The media `preload` attribute would be useful to explore, although it will only work [in some browsers](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/04/12/html5-video-preload/).

The HTML5 specification seems to anticipate your exact use-case:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-media-preload

> **Note**: Authors might switch the attribute from "none" or "metadata" to "auto"
>   dynamically once the user begins playback. For example, on a page with
>   many videos this might be used to indicate that the many videos are
>   not to be downloaded unless requested, but that once one is requested
>   it is to be downloaded aggressively.

Comment: I would definitely look into this. I was aware of the 'preload' attribute, but I thought it would only be useful before playing some of the videos. If dynamically changing that attribute prevents the video to be buffered this would be the way to go. I'll let you know what I found. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Switching the preload attribute is not working for maintaining the buffer. Its only useful when the app starts. Once you hit play, you cannot stop buffering. The only way of doing it so far is deleting the src attribute, which I find to be a very poor way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for following-up with your comment. I suspected this might be the case, but the note I posted above made me hopeful it might work in some browsers.  In either case, adjusting the preload settings would help reduce the bandwidth requirements of a page with multiple video elements - just not quite as intelligently as you had hoped.